# git push -u origin main error (other name than master)

Tags: git, rename, naming-conventions, git-push

Nnaming conventions for git has changed, and it is recommended now to use other naming for **Master** branch.

I've come across an issue while trying to initialize my awesome project to a new git repo with name **Main**

```
git init
git add -A
git remote add origin https://github.com/{MYREPO}.git
git push -u origin main
```

which ended up throwing the following error

```
error: src refspec main does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/{MYREPO}.git'
```

git version 2.16.1.windows.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution** Assuming this is brand new repo, this is the solution

```
git branch -m master main
git push -u origin main
```

**Explanation**

`git init` creates a local origin named `master` ([ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init))

> ```
> -b <branch-name
> --initial-branch=<branch-name>
> ```
>
> Use the specified name for the initial branch in the newly created repository.
>
> If not specified, fall back to
> the default name: `master`.

That is the reason for git to throw that error.

Use `git show-ref` to see what refs you have. ([ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push-ltrefspecgt82308203))

If it shows `refs/heads/master`, you can rename it to whatever you want using `git branch -m master {name}`

Comment: Why do I get `! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)` with this?  I have in `git show-ref` the following: `refs/heads/main` and `refs/remotes/origin/master` and all my files are in `master` and I want them in `main`.  Seem like this changing name thing is not helpful to noobies at git which was already complicated to me.

Comment: @BrianWiley I think you need to run `$ git remote rename master main` as per the instructions described at git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Comment: Thanks, I have been using [these](https://stevenmortimer.com/5-steps-to-change-github-default-branch-from-master-to-main/) instructions which probably work for any project not just R.  Is doing it this way a harder way?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's R or any other language, git should work the same for anything. Did you try the above command?